# How to load hasMany in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
App.Offer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),

    products: DS.hasMany('product')
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),

    offer: DS.belongsTo('offer')
});
```

And the server is answering with record and array of ids in this way (for example if the rest adapter asks for /offers/1):

```
 { "offer": [ { "id": 1, "name": "aaaaaaaaa", "description": "aaaa", "product_ids": [ 1, 2 ] } ] }
```

but now how can I get the products? I have a route like this:

```
App.OffersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var offer = this.get('store').find('offer', 1);
        return offer
    }
});
```

In Ember guide is written that if you want the products you should do:

```
offer.get('products');
```

Ok, but where should I put this? in the model hook? in a Controller property?
I've tried many things but I can see no network request to products?id[]=1&id[]=2 as I expected (the server is responding correctly to this request);

Can someone please give an example showing how I can find an offer, its products and use this data in my template?

Comment: Which DS adapter are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the RESTAdapter your data needs to be in this format (if you don't want to return it in this format you can create a custom serializer and fix up the json).

2 differences:

1. the item under `offer` shouldn't be an array, since you were looking for a single item it should be an object
2. the key `product_ids` should be `products`, `product_ids` is the format that the ActiveModelAdapter/ActiveModelSerializer use.

#### JSON

```
{
   "offer":
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"aaaaaaaaa",
         "description":"aaaa",
         "products":[
            1,
            2
         ]
      }
 }
```

The hasMany relationship should be marked as async if you're expecting it to be returned in a separate payload.

```
App.Offer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),    
    products: DS.hasMany('product', {async:true})
});
```

I hooked it up in jsbin below, but I didn't hook up a result from `products?ids[]=1&ids[]=2` (note `ids[]=`, not `id[]=`), if you check the network tab you'll see the request being issued (but it'll crash since there is no result).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/345/edit

Comment: Kingpin for president! :)

Comment: Why does exist this difference between returning one record (single object "offer") and returning many (array "offers" of objects)? I found that I can always return an array "offers" even if I have to return only one record, and it works; so I would like to understand why there is this distinction